# Why is "error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type using unique_ptr" fixed by adding an empty destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, pimpl-idiom

I am Pimpling off the class `STFT`. Compiles just fine with this in the header:

```
class STFT; // pimpl off to prevent point name clash

class Whatever
{
private:
    STFT* stft;
```

and this in the implementation:

```
#include "STFT.h"
Whatever::Whatever() : stft(new STFT()) {
// blah blah
}

Whatever::~Whatever() {
    delete stft; // pure evil
}
```

However, switching to `std::unique_ptr<STFT> stft;` over the raw pointer in the header, and removing the destructor, I get

> error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'STFT'
>               static_assert(sizeof(_Tp) > 0, "default_delete can not delete incomplete type");

But if I simply supply an empty destructor `Whatever::~Whatever(){}`, then it compiles fine. This has me completely stumped. Please fill me in on what this meaningless destructor is doing for me.

Comment: Tested it without error just now :/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If we go to the cppreference document for [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

> `std::unique_ptr` may be constructed for an incomplete type `T`, such as
>   to facilitate the use as a handle in the Pimpl idiom. **If the default
>   deleter is used, `T` must be complete at the point in code where the
>   deleter is invoked, which happens in the destructor, move assignment
>   operator, and reset member function of `std::unique_ptr`**. (Conversely,
>   `std::shared_ptr` can't be constructed from a raw pointer to incomplete
>   type, but can be destroyed where `T` is incomplete).

We can see in the below code:

```
#include <memory>

class STFT; // pimpl off to prevent point name clash

class Whatever
{
    public:
     ~Whatever() ;
    private:
      std::unique_ptr<STFT> stft;
} ;

//class STFT{};

Whatever::~Whatever() {}

int main(){}
```

The requirements are not fulfilled when the defintion of `STFT` is commented before the destructor of `Whatever` is defined since this requires the destructor for `stft` which in turn requires `STFT` to be complete.

So it seems likely that in your *implementation* file `STFT` is complete when `Whatever::~Whatever()` is defined but otherwise the defaulted one is created without the `STFT` being complete.

Answer (score 32):

My usual idiom for providing such destructors is (in the implementation file):

```
#include "STFT.h"

Whatever::~Whatever() = default;
```

The important thing is that it needs to be somewhere where the pointed-to type(s) are complete.

Comment: Using that syntax gives same error. I need to explicitly declare an empty dtor.

Comment: That depends **where** you put it.  If you put it in the header, where `STFT` is incomplete, then it's as bad as letting the compiler generate it where it's needed.  It needs to be in the implementation file, after `#include <stft>`, where all the pointed-to types are complete.  If it didn't work, I wouldn't be using it myself.

Comment: Ahhhh. Ok. That works

Comment: Is there any difference whatsoever compared to `Whatever::~Whatever() {}`? That one is 7 characters shorter :-P

Comment: Technically, there is a different between an *explicitly-defaulted* destructor and a *user-supplied* empty destructor, but I can't think of a practical difference right now.  I find the explicit `default` faster to read, and damn the expense!

Comment: This is the actual answer. Dtor should be in the compilation unit, not in the header. I lost half a day on finding why it doesn't compile.