# In pimpl design using std::unique_ptr, if dtor is put in implementation file BEFORE Impl type definition, why is it compiling ok?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, incomplete-type, pimpl-idiom

First, I know that in pimpl design with `std::unique_ptr`, the destructor of the client class cannot be inline and needs to be implemented in the implementation file because the `unique_ptr` destructor needs a complete type for the pointed-to type. I already read the following pages:

[Is std::unique_ptr required to know the full definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012157/is-stdunique-ptrt-required-to-know-the-full-definition-of-t)

[Why is "error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type using unique_ptr" fixed by adding an empty destructor? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072862/why-is-error-invalid-application-of-sizeof-to-an-incomplete-type-using-uniqu)

My question is different.

Here is my code:

`someclass.h`:

```cpp
#include <memory>
class SomeClass {
public:
  void do_some_thing();
  ~SomeClass();
  SomeClass();

private:
  class SomeClassImp;
  std::unique_ptr<SomeClassImp> ptr;
};
```

`someclass.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "someclass.h"
#include <iostream>

// TODO: place before definition of SomeClassImp is also ok, why?
// SomeClass::~SomeClass() = default;
// SomeClass::SomeClass() = default;


// Why dtor here is also compiling ok? Here SomeClassImp is not a complete type
// actually if we print SomeClassImp using sizeof(..) inside the dtor, the compiling will fail requiring a complete type of SomeClassImp. 
// Then why is the compile ok with the unique_ptr requirements that the SomeClassImp type
// should be complete here?
SomeClass::~SomeClass(){};
SomeClass::SomeClass(){};


class SomeClass::SomeClassImp {
public:
  void implementation() { std::cout << "implementing...\n"; }
};
void SomeClass::do_some_thing() { ptr->implementation(); }
// following code is ok, it's understandable since here the SomeClassImp type is complete

// SomeClass::~SomeClass() = default;
// SomeClass::SomeClass() = default;
// following code is also ok

// SomeClass::~SomeClass(){};
// SomeClass::SomeClass(){};
```

----Edit-----

After some experiments, it has something to do with the template function's two stage name lookup rules:

- std::unique_ptr is a template class, so its destructor is dependent on the template parameter
- The name lookup rules apply to the destructor and will be instantiated after the compiler has already known all definitions in the same translation unit.

Above might be the reason why it compiles.

Comment: [It compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/Ecof8K5xs) with the destructor inline in `SomeClass` as well. It just doesn't actually call `SomeClassImp` destructor. Calling `delete` on a pointer to incomplete class is not ill-formed, but destructor is not called, so it may or may not behave correctly.

Comment: **[expr.delete]/5** If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of deletion and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a deallocation function, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It not compile if you have header file and cpp file separately, which is a must for pimpl design.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It seems like compiler have compiling sequence optimization inside one translation unit

Comment: I've been wrong that the destructor wasn't called; I've been misled by the fact that your original example doesn't actually create `SomeClassImp`. Once I add that, [the destructor is in fact called](https://godbolt.org/z/osd4fbjar).

Comment: I think I know what happens. It is unspecified whether the point of instantiation of a function template - such as `std::unique_ptr` destructor - is immediately after where it's used, or at the end of the translation unit (or something like that - I could never remember the details, but the important part is that the compiler is allowed to postpone to the end of the source file). Apparently, clang and gcc do that; `unique_ptr` destructor is instantiated at the end of the file where `SomeClassImp` is complete. So basically, it's just a lucky coincidence.

Comment: Now, moving `~SomeClass() {}` definition into the header would create a problem for any source file that uses `SomeClass` - a file that includes `someclass.h` but doesn't actually define `SomeClassImp`. If `~SomeClass()` is defined in the header, this using source would try to instantiate it, but that'd fail due to `SomeClassImp` being incomplete.

Comment: Having `~SomeClass()` destructor in the implementation file above the definition of `SomeClassImp` is either undefined or unspecified behavior (I don't remember which, and am too lazy to look it up; like I said, it has to do with the point of instantiation of function templates, in case you want to research it yourself).

Comment: POI (Point of instantiation) might be delayed to end of TU(translation unit), making out of order compile. But IIRC, if any possible POI have different meaning the program would be ill-formed NDR (no diagnostic required), which is the case here.